# Understanding link function with $apply in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I was going through a tutorial, which can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/14q6WxHyhWuVxEIqwww1?p=preview). I am having trouble understanding the event listener on the customer directive `<hello-world/>`.

App is laid out in the following way:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.7"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="color" placeholder="Enter a color"/>
    <hello-world/>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('helloWorld',function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<p style="background-color:{{color}}">Hello World</p>',
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
      elem.bind('click',function(){
        elem.css('background-color','white');
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.color="white";
        });
      });
      elem.bind('mouseover',function(){
        elem.css('cursor','pointer');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

My question is why does the callback in the click listener include the `$apply` method? Why can't one just have `scope.color="white";`

Comment: `elem.bind` happens outside of Angular context - `$scope.$apply` manually triggers a digest cycle so that the View gets updated

Comment: How could elem.bind be happening outside of the Angular context if the callback contains Angular syntax?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "callback contains Angular syntax"... What I'm saying is that when the callback happens asynchronously, Angular is not aware of it, and so it does not update bindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `helloWorld` directive currently looks at its parent scope (in other cases, if you have the property `scope: true` in your directive, it'll have an isolate scope, but that's not the case here.)

In directives that look at their parent scopes for data, there's no two-way data-binding going on. In other words, the directive will initially *receive* information from its parent scope, but it won't *send* updates to the parent scope. This is why we call `scope.$apply`. This manually forces a digest cycle to happen on the scope, which will run through all of its watchers and look for changes.

That's what people mean when it happens "out of context".

To understand more about the digest cycle, I'd take a look at this [article](http://teropa.info/build-your-own-angular/build_your_own_angularjs_sample.pdf) that basically shows you how to build your own version of AngularJS at a very high level of abstraction.

To add to all of this, if you had `scope: true` in the directive and thus allowed the directive to have its own isolate scope, you wouldn't need the `scope.$apply` method. However, the isolated scope data would *only* be available to that directive and no parent scopes, unless you explicitly grant parent scopes access to the data (for example, by manually looking up the scope's parent, which isn't desirable. For this type of thing, you'd want to look into the [`controllerAs` syntax](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/), which is relevant here only as far as namespacing components is concerned.)

## Edit

```
  elem.bind('click',function(){
    elem.css('background-color','white');
    //scope.$apply(function(){
      //scope.color="white";
    //});
  });
```

The above will still change the background color of the element to white. This has nothing to do with the `scope`.

```
  elem.bind('click',function(){
    elem.css('background-color','white');
    scope.$apply(function(){
      scope.color="white";
    });
  });
```

The above forces the parent scope to show the text name of the color "white" in the text box (this one: `<input type="text" ng-model="color" placeholder="Enter a color"/>`).

The `ng-model` refers to `scope.color`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Great explanation. If you go to the plunker and remove `$apply` and just use `scope.color = "white"` the app still works as intented i.e. the color of the element changes back to white on click. Does this mean that something else other than $apply is kicking off the digest cycle? Or `scope:false` isthe default in a directive?

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst, Yeah the color still changes back, because of the line `elem.css('background-color','white');`.

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst, however `scope.white` doesn't propagate up to the text box, which is supposed to show the current selected color.

Comment: Ah yes you are right it doesn't propagate to the top. Thanks @Josh Beam.